# select ... where (a=1 or b=min(b)) GROUP BY xy

Tags: mysql

I have table gall_photos, which contains photos of many galleries

- id (int)
- gall_id (int)
- filename (varchar)
- position (int)
- preview (tinyint 1)
- date_add (datetime)

Now I would like get list of photos (for summary preview), one of each gall_id, but if any has preview 1, then this, else photo with lowest position number. Finally sorted by date_add

```
select * 
from gall_photos 
where (preview = 1 or position = min(position)) 
group by gall_id 
order by date_add
```

this query returns error (if "or position = min(position)" is used )

Please, any idea?

EDIT (12.1. 18:50UTC): There is possible to check preview for more photos in one gallery (gall_id), then I need one of them, again the lowest position

Comment: Remove the extra parentheses around your where statement

Comment: WHERE CLAUSE is not allowed with GROUP BY use having instead, see my answer below. thanks

Comment: Ohh, I forgot totally, thanks everyone for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
select * 
from gall_photos x 
where (preview = 1 or (position = 
                             (SELECT min(x2.position)
                              FROM gall_photos x2 
                              WHERE x.gall_id = x2.gall_id
                              Group By x2.gall_id)
                      and not exists 
                              (select 1 
                               from gall_photos x2 
                               where x2.gall_id=x.gall_id 
                               and x2.preview=1)
                        )
       );
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14ed7/10)

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you. I am going to vote new president, then i will try...

Comment: Won't that return BOTH!?!?!

Comment: Yes, this works correctly. But now I discover one more condition...  my EDIT above.. If I have checked more then one preview, than I get all of them :-(

Comment: OK, I solved it by adding GROUP BY gall_id at the end of query

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, gall_id, filename, position, preview, date_add
from gall_photos 
where position in (select min(position)from gall_photos) 
or
exists (select preview from gall_photos where preview = 1)
group by gall_id
order by date_add;
```

Comment: this is not checking position within group it is checking positions for all gall_id.

Comment: This returns 1st position of each gallery and if preview checked (=1), then all lines for each preview=1 too.

Comment: I have updated my answer can you check if it is ok if you haven't solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

rs's solution is very close, but if you have a record where preview=1 and it does not have the lowest position for the gall_id, he's going to give you both the preview=1 and the lowest position. So I think what you want is:

```
select * 
from gall_photos g1
where preview = 1
  or not exists (select * from gall_photos g2 where g2.gall_id=g1.gall_id and g2.preview=1)
  and position = (select min(g3.position) from gall_photos g3
    where g3.gall_id=g1.gall_id)
order by date_add
```

Comment: Yes, I think rs changed his answer after my post. Note DnD's comment is no longer applicable to the current state of that answer. Whatever. Personally I think mine is a little less cryptic, but whatever works for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
SELECT a.gall_id
     , COALESCE(c.position,a.position) position
  FROM gall_photos a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT gall_id,MIN(position) min_position FROM gall_photos GROUP BY gall_id) b 
    ON b.gall_id = a.gall_id 
   AND b.min_position = a.position
  LEFT
  JOIN gall_photos c
    ON c.gall_id = a.gall_id
   AND c.preview = 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this query returns only first placed image (lowest position), but if I have checked preview, return position of that (but id, filename still first line). In case I have checked more preview, I get more lines with the same (first position) line, but position of previewed :-)

Comment: Can you illustrate this problem with some sample data

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE CLAUSE` is not allowed with `GROUP BY`

Use `HAVING` :

```
select * 
from gall_photos 
group by gall_id 
having (preview = 1 or position = min(position)) 
order by date_add
```

Comment: OK, thank you, "having" is new for me. Query now works without error, but still not work correctly. This return first of each gallery (trimmed by GROUP BY)